# get the count and group them

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm using python with pymongo.

In one of mongo collection saving different messages from different countries.
Every document will have one country short code to indicate their country.
May i know how can i group them and get the count for every country code?

For example

```
{u'tweet': u"If you're male and own an iPhone, get new star soccer. Holy shit it's addictive", u'loc': u"US", u'_id': ObjectId('515ecace4e18187ca67ddfcb'), u'time': datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 5, 12, 59, 57)}
```

above is one row of message with location, and in my database may have US, SG, AU and so on...  different locations will have differences number of messages. How can i query or is that any possible approach? Thanks

**UPDATE**

The reason i want to get the count is because i need to inject the data to the following code for [google chart generate the chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) for me.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);
```

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the aggregation framework.

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$loc", count: {$sum:1}}}
```

This will give you back for each country how many time it was mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is to group the records into a dictionary as you read the MongoClient cursor. Each key would be a country, and each value would be a list of all records for that country.

```
import pymongo
con = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = con.myDatabase
col = db.myCollection
cursor = col.find()

data = {}
for c in cursor:
    if not c["loc"] in data.keys():
        data[c["loc"]] = []
    data[c["name"]].append(c)
```

This of course assumes that every record has the "loc" key from your example.

Comment: Also, len(data["key"]) will get you the count for any country.

Comment: Thanks for your great respond. with your method to get the count, is it possible to publish to the javascript? Please check update. Thanks

Comment: why would you want to do the work in the client when you can just query the database server for aggregated count by location?